# How to cast string to IP Address in Spring Data JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table that contains ranges of IP addresses with starting and ending values in their own columns. These columns are of type varchar. I need to query the database to get rows for which the range covers that IP Address.

Here is my query that works perfectly fine with PGSQL:

```
select * from ip_whitelist iw where iw.ip_address::inet <= '1.1.1.54'::inet and iw.ip_address_end::inet >= '1.1.1.54'::inet
```

1.1.1.54 is just a dummy value here that will be replaced by a variable in my JPA query:

Here's how I'm trying to run this query via JPA Repository:

```
@Query("select ip from AllowedIp ip where CAST(ip.ipAddress AS inet) <= CAST((?1) AS inet) and CAST(ip.ipAddressEnd AS inet) >= CAST((?1) AS inet)")
List<AllowedIp> findDuplicatesByIP(String ipAddress);
```

My problem is I need to cast the `ipAddress` and `ipAddressEnd` columns to `inet` within this JPA query so I can use the <= and >= operators to search if a range already covers the given IP. The JPA query mentioned above is throwing an error when I try to start my Tomcat application. Here's the stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : inet [select ip from com.uxl.dataobjects.domain.AllowedIp ip where CAST(ip.ipAddress AS inet) <= CAST((?1) AS inet) and CAST(ip.ipAddressEnd AS inet) >= CAST((?1) AS inet)]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor69.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
        ... 101 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : inet [select ip from com.uxl.dataobjects.domain.AllowedIp ip where CAST(ip.ipAddress AS inet) <= CAST((?1) AS inet) and CAST(ip.ipAddressEnd AS inet) >= CAST((?1) AS inet)]
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
        ... 107 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : inet
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CastFunctionNode.resolve(CastFunctionNode.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processCastFunction(HqlSqlWalker.java:1097)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.functionCall(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2748)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1342)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4686)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4252)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2104)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2029)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:796)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:597)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
        ... 115 more
```

Possible Solutions I've explored that didn't work out:

1. Cast the String IP to InetAddress data type in java instead. This cannot work because the table columns are still in string type so they will still need to be cast in order to use the operators.
2. Get all rows and filter in Java. While this may work, this seems to be an impractical solution, not to mention bad practice.
3. I found [Vlad Mihalcea's guide](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/) to using custom hibernate types and inlcuded the package in my project. However, I can't figure how to use it for casting in my query, because its primarily used in entities where the column data type is Inet. In my case, columns in the table are of type varchar.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestion on how I can get this to run will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1: Added another possible solution I've tried.

Comment: You can use the interface `AttributeConverter<X,Y>` to teach Hibernate how to convert data between two types. Not sure if that will help in your case, you may have to implement new SQL Function templates directly in the Dialect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have realized the answer was there all along. This is not an ideal solution, but good enough for now until Hibernate natively supports inet data type.

The solution is to use `nativeQuery = true` parameter in @Query. So the final query becomes:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from ip_whitelist where CAST(ip_address AS inet) <= CAST((?1) AS inet) and CAST(ip_address_end AS inet) >= CAST((?1) AS inet)")
```

Answer (score -1):

The built-in cidr and inet types will do what you want and provide suitable operators and for more details regarding cast in postgres use this [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)

```
SELECT '192.168.1.19'::inet << '192.168.1.0/24'::cidr
```

The above query helps you give ip address directly and if needed to cast it then
make use of the below links that helps in those conversions

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.20.0107211126100.4270-100000@Larry.bks

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/F28A2B83DFE0D411A7B3006097487147468FDB%40sv7007.scania.se

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html#:~:text=PostgreSQL%20offers%20data%20types%20to,functions%20(see%20Section%209.12)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-net-types.html#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20offers%20data%20types%20to,functions%20(see%20Section%209.12)).

Comment: If you look at my question, I already have the query and am casting the string to inet. My query works perfectly fine when run in Postgres. The problem lies when I try to do this in hibernate. It doesn't work because hibernate does not know how to convert.